# Populate empty table of 2 columns (both foreign key references) with the data the cols are referencing from 2 other tables PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables that I am referencing:

1) `Practitioner`:

```
+------+-------------------+---------------+
| PKey |     FullName      | PhonePersonal |
+------+-------------------+---------------+
|    2 | Dr. Albert Wong   |     126777744 |
|    3 | Dr. William Kwong |     155556666 |
|    4 | Dr. Jonathan Chan |    4567888888 |
|    5 | Dr. Alice Lim     |      66655532 |
|    6 | Dr. Jerry Wong    |     123455578 |
|    7 | Dr. Louis Lane    |     167844444 |
|    8 | Dr. Steven Teng   |     122223000 |
+------+-------------------+---------------+
```

2) `Center`:

```
+------+--------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
| Pkey |     Name     |           AddressStreet           | AddressCity  |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
|   10 | Klinik Satu  | 1, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | TTDI         |
|   11 | Klinik Dua   | 2, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | Pudu         |
|   12 | Klinik Tiga  | 3, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | Sentul       |
|   13 | Klinik Empat | 4, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | Sentul Timur |
|   14 | Klinik Lima  | 5, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | Cheras       |
|   15 | Klinik Enam  | 6, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | Bangsar      |
|   16 | Klinik Tujuh | 7, Jalan Harmoni, Taman Kesihatan | Brickfields  |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
```

And a Table `Location` that has 2 foreign keys referencing columns:

1. `Loc_PractitionerId` referencing  `PractitionerId` in table `Practitioner`.
2. `Loc_CenterId` referencing  `Center_Id` in table `Center`.

What is the best way to populate `Location` with the data it is/will be referencing ?

The desired output being:

```
CREATE TABLE Location (

    Loc_PractitionerId  INTEGER  FOREIGN KEY,
    Loc_CenterId INTEGER  FOREIGN KEY
);
```

As such:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+
|  Loc_practitionerId INT   |  Loc_centerId INT   |
+---------------------------+---------------------+
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
| fkey data: PractitionerId | fkey data: CenterId |
+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

or with the mock data, as such:

```
+------------------------+------------------+
| Loc_practitionerId INT | Loc_centerId INT |
+------------------------+------------------+
|                      2 |               10 |
|                      3 |               11 |
|                      4 |               12 |
|                      5 |               13 |
|                      6 |               14 |
|                      7 |               15 |
|                      8 |               16 |
+------------------------+------------------+
```

I have attempted to use the following query:

```
 INSERT INTO "Location" ( "Loc_practitionerId", "Loc_centerId") 
 values 
    ((SELECT "PractitionerId" FROM "Practitioner"),
     (SELECT "CenterId" from "Center"))
```

But get:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

I'm using PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template greatly increases you chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case the best way to populate location is (most likely) "insert into location (PractitionerId, Center_id) select ..." but without DDL and sample data with expected output the "..." part cannot be addressed.

Comment: Thanks, for the prompt. I have edited , hopefully the question is a little better formatted now.

Comment: Well you have taken a step in the right direction. However, there is still a way to go. Whet is needed is DDL for Practitioner and Center tables. Also provide sample *data values* for those tables as formatted text or insert statements, and the result of those data. Essentially, in one way or another this will come down to "insert into location( loc_practitionerId,   lLoc_centerId) values ( *practitionerId,ceneterId*); " But that may wind up as a select depending on the data available at insert time.

Comment: Hey @Belayer - have added as suggested and also extrapolated your suggestion but I getting a error thrown as per above.

Comment: The answer @forpas provides is correct for this situation (almost exactly what I came up with after your last comment). However, I think it is important for you to understand that while it works with contrived data in a real scenario it has about a 0 probability of producing a valid result. 
This results from there being no common column/data value on which to base the join. You are depending of the relative order of 2 independent values matching correctly. That is  extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` window function to link the 2 tables:

```
insert into Location(Loc_PractitionerId, Loc_CenterId)
select p.pkey, c.pkey
from (
  select pkey, row_number() over (order by pkey) rn
  from Practitioner
) p inner join (
  select pkey, row_number() over (order by pkey) rn
  from Center
) c 
on c.rn = p.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pELMNBypcZe8fbhqpyiWpe/0).
Results:

```
| loc_practitionerid | loc_centerid |
| ------------------ | ------------ |
| 2                  | 10           |
| 3                  | 11           |
| 4                  | 12           |
| 5                  | 13           |
| 6                  | 14           |
| 7                  | 15           |
| 8                  | 16           |
```

Comment: Perfect- Thanks! This is just what I was after !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a cross join to be inserted into the location table:

```
INSERT INTO "Location" ( "Loc_practitionerId", "Loc_centerId") 
SELECT p."PractitionerId", c."CenterId" 
FROM "Practitioner" p
  cross join "Center" c;
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really [avoid](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: Yeah the Schema using capitals for col naming was something I had no choice in implementing....but you're absolutely right it's a PITA.

I'm getting:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
> LINE 4:   cross join from "Center" c

Comment: Got it - nearly what I'm looking for, but want the data in the format of the mock data I just added for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

OK so you are wanting to build every combination. You get this with a CROSS JOIN of your tables.  The reason you get this error is you have stuffed your select inside a values clause.  Each element in that clause must produce 0 or 1 row, your select produces 1 row for each row in the table. The solution is to elminate the values clause. Check the format, you will see it is not needed just select is fine. So:

```
 insert into "Location" ( "Loc_practitionerId", "Loc_centerId") 
      select "PractitionerId", "Practitioner",
        from "Practioner"
       cross join "Center";
```

And GET RID of those double quotes.

Comment: No it isn't every combination i'm after. It's only the data in the respective columns. Maybe if I change the sample data that may be more obvious.